# Parallelism between past perfect and present continuous

Tags: grammar, parallelism

In the following sentence:

> Anyone who has stumbled glumly through a British airport recently,
>   trapped in endless queues, will already know the stench of bogus
>   security hanging heavy in the air. I always knew at some subliminal
>   level that even as my nail scissors were being seized by a censorious
>   official,some monstrous breach the size of the Channel **was
>   blithely** disregarded elsewhere.

The part which is bold seems incorrect to me. I think it should be "**was being blithely**".

Although if "**while**" was used as in, "*while some monstrous breach the size of the Channel was blithely disregarded elsewhere*", it would have been correct.

How should one ensure parallelism between something which is happening now and something in past which still happens?

Answer (score -1):

Your exemplar isn't bad. I would alter it slightly, for even better parallelism.

> "Anyone who has stumbled glumly through a British airport recently, trapped in endless queues, will already know *how* the stench of bogus security hangs heavy in the air. I always knew at some subliminal level that even as a censorious official was *sadistically* seizing my nail scissors, a *lackadaisical security guard* was blithely disregarding some monstrous breach the size of the Channel."

In my version, the parallelism is more uniform: the *censorious official* parallels the *lackadaisical guard*, and the *sadistically seizing* parallels the *blithely disregarding*. As for my addition of *how*, it may not be necessary, but I like it anyway.